# Expand matrix based on vector

Tags: numpy

I want to turn matrix `A` into matrix `B`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there a better/more efficient approach with NumPy than the following?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.02, 0.05, 0.05],
              [0.35, 0.10, 0.45],
              [0.08, 0.25, 0.15]])

w = np.array([0.75, 0.25])

B = np.insert(a, 9, a[2, :]).reshape(4, 3)
B = np.insert(B.T, 12, B[:, 2]).reshape(4, 4).T
B[2:4, :] = np.multiply(B[2:4, :].T, w).T
```

Answer (score 1):

`.insert` isn't a good choice here because numpy needs to allocate memory to create a whole new array every time you do so. Instead, just pre-allocate the size of array you need, and then *assign* to its slices.

```
a = np.array([[0.02, 0.05, 0.05],
              [0.35, 0.10, 0.45],
              [0.08, 0.25, 0.15]])

w = np.array([0.75, 0.25])

b_shape = tuple(s + 1 for s in a.shape) # We need one more row and column than a

b = np.zeros(b_shape)    # Create zero array of required shape

b[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]] = a   # Set a in the top left corner

b[:, -1] = b[:, -2]         # Set last column from second-last column
b[-1, :] = b[-2, :]         # Set last row from second-last row

b[-w.shape[0]:, :] = b[-w.shape[0]:, :] * w[:, None]  # Multiply last two rows with `w`
```

`w[:, None]` makes `w` a column vector (a `2x1` matrix), and numpy broadcasts the shapes to do the correct elementwise multiplication.

This gives us the required `b`:

```
array([[0.02  , 0.05  , 0.05  , 0.05  ],
       [0.35  , 0.1   , 0.45  , 0.45  ],
       [0.06  , 0.1875, 0.1125, 0.1125],
       [0.02  , 0.0625, 0.0375, 0.0375]])
```

---

Putting this in a function to compare runtimes against your approach:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#% Define functions

def func_insert(a, w):
    B = np.insert(a, a.size, a[-1, :]).reshape(a.shape[0]+1, a.shape[1])
    B = np.insert(B.T, B.size, B[:, -1]).reshape(a.shape[0]+1, a.shape[1]+1).T
    B[-w.shape[0]:, :] = np.multiply(B[-w.shape[0]:, :].T, w).T
    return B

def func_prealloc(a, w):
    b_shape = tuple(s + 1 for s in a.shape)
    b = np.zeros(b_shape)

    b[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]] = a
    b[:, -1] = b[:, -2]
    b[-1, :] = b[-2, :]

    b[-w.shape[0]:, :] = b[-w.shape[0]:, :] * w[:, None]
    return b

#% Time function calls
sizes = [3, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10_000]
times = np.zeros((len(sizes), 2))

for i, size in enumerate(sizes):
    a = np.random.random((size, size))
    w = np.random.random((2,))
    
    times[i, 0] = timeit.timeit("func_insert(a, w)", globals=globals(), number=10) / 10
    print(".")
    times[i, 1] = timeit.timeit("func_prealloc(a, w)", globals=globals(), number=10) / 10
    print("x")
    
#% Plot results

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(sizes, times[:, 0], label="Insert")
ax.plot(sizes, times[:, 1], label="Prealloc")
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('Array size (NxN)')
ax.set_ylabel('Time per function call (s)')
ax.grid(True)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]]

There's a consistent 3-5x speedup by preallocating.

Comment: b=np.pad(a, ((0,1),(0,1)), mode='edge')

Comment: @AlexAlex Thank you for your comment! Nice and lean. A bit slower than the approaches above though. Thanks anyway. Obviously very handy if a lot of iterations are not required.